# Weird semi-transparent lines and rectangles problem in Blender Internal Render (2.79)

Tags: rendering, animation

I just made this account to see if anyone could help me on an issue I have

As the title says I have a weird issue with rendering an animation with the Blender internal render where there would be random lines and rectangles and random spots in my render and I have no clue as to what's causing this issue, some help would be very appreciated :/

[image: 1st screenshot]
[image: 2nd screenshot]

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: Hello! Add some more info about your scene: viewport screenshots, material settings or even .blend file if you can.

Comment: @SergeL Hello, I couldn't upload the .blend here for some reason so I uploaded it to mega

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like problem comes from "Light" texture, it uses gradient to darken some shadeless materials and somehow final result has stripe artifacts.

After playing with the settings, I've found two ways to prevent it (still don't know why is it even happen):

1. Decrease "Light" texture's *Filter size*

[image]

2. Enable *Autosmooth* on the ground object:

[image]

P.S. didn't test it on other camera angles, problem might appear again.

Comment: Youre a goddamn legend man thanks so much!